# Powershell class first instance misbehaving

Tags: powershell, class, oop

I am getting my feet wet with PS classes, by trying to implement a path type identifier class. Basically I want to pass a string in and identify variations on file system and registry paths. Mostly it is working, but oddly the first item I test, no matter what it is, the properties are blank when I look, though no error shows up. And it seems like the results are actually from the previous instance, at least for the "successful" instances. Thrown exceptions seem to be working as expected. So, when `$test = @('C:\folder', 'D:\', 'C:', 'K:', '\\Server\Folder\*'`, '\junk', '?:'), my results will be

```
C:\folder



D:\
 FileSystem_Folder
 LocalDisk folder

C:
 FileSystem_Drive
 OpticalDisk drive

K:
 FileSystem_Drive
 LocalDisk drive

\\Server\Folder\*
 FileSystem_Drive
 Unknown drive

! \junk
 Not Identified: \junk

! ?:
 Not Identified: ?:
```

This is the code in question.

```
class PxPath {
    # Properties
    hidden [array]$validPathTypes = @('FileSystem_Drive', 'FileSystem_Folder', 'FileSystem_File', 'Registry_Key', 'Registry_Property')
    hidden [hashtable]$regExLookup = @{
        registryHive = '^(?<hive>HKCC|HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG|HKCR|HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT|HKCU|HKEY_CURRENT_USER|HKLM|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)(?<seperator>:)?$'
        registryPath = '^(?<hive>HKCC|HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG|HKCR|HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT|HKCU|HKEY_CURRENT_USER|HKLM|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)(?<seperator>:)?\\(?<remainder>.+)$'
        fileSystemDriveOnly= '^(?<drive>[a-zA-Z]:)(\\)?$'
        fileSystemDrivePath = '^(?<drive>[a-zA-Z]:)\\(?<remainder>.+)$'
        fileSystemUNCPath = '^(?<server>\\\\[^<>:"/\\\|]*)\\(?<remainder>.+)$'
    }
    hidden [hashtable]$driveTypeLookup = @{
        0 = 'Unknown'
        1 = 'NoRootDirectory'
        2 = 'RemovableDisk'
        3 = 'LocalDisk'
        4 = 'NetworkDrive'
        5 = 'OpticalDisk'
        6 = 'RamDisk'
    }
    [string]$Description = $null
    [string]$Type = $null

    # Constructors
    PxPath ([string]$path) {
        $this.PathType($path)
    }
    PxPath ([string]$path, [string]$pathType) {
        if ($this.validPathTypes -contains $pathType) {
             $this.PathType($path)
             if ($this.Type -ne $pathType) {
                Throw "$($this.Type) does not match: $pathType"
             }
        } else {
            Throw "Not a valid path type: $pathType"
        }
    }

    hidden [void] PathType ([string]$path) {
        [string]$driveType = $null
        [string]$extension = $null
        [string]$extension = $null

        switch -regex ($path) {
            $this.regExLookup.fileSystemDriveOnly {
                $driveType = $this.driveTypeLookup.Get_Item([int](Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computerName:. -filter:"name='$($matches.drive)'" | Select DriveType).DriveType)
                $this.Description = "$driveType drive"
                $this.Type = 'FileSystem_Drive'
            }
            $this.regExLookup.fileSystemDrivePath {
                $driveType = $this.driveTypeLookup.Get_Item([int](Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computerName:. -filter:"name='$($matches.drive)'" | Select DriveType).DriveType)
                if ($extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($path)) {
                    $this.Description = "$driveType file"
                    $this.Type = 'FileSystem_File'
                } else {
                    $this.Description = "$driveType folder"
                    $this.Type = 'FileSystem_Folder'
                }
            }
            $this.regExLookup.fileSystemUNCPath {
                if ($extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($path)) {
                    $this.Description = "UNC file"
                    $this.Type = 'FileSystem_File'
                } else {
                    $this.Description = "UNC folder"
                    $this.Type = 'FileSystem_Folder'
                }
            }
            $this.regExLookup.registryPath {
            }
            default {
                Throw "Not Identified: $path"
            }
        }
    }
}

CLS
$test = @('C:\folder', 'D:\', 'C:', 'K:', '\\Server\Folder\*', '\junk', '?:')

foreach ($testitem in $test) {
    $path = try {
        [PxPath]::New($testitem)
        Write-Host $testitem
        Write-Host " $($path.Type)"
        Write-Host " $($path.Description)"
        Write-Host
    } catch {
        Write-Host "! $testitem"
        Write-Host " $($_.Exception.Message)"
        Write-Host
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue is something I just don't understand with classes, but I guess a bug in PowerShell that I need to work around could also be the culprit.

Comment: Move the assignment to `$path` _inside_ the try block - the entire `try`/`catch` will need to execute before the assignment occurs, so otherwise you're always looking at the _previous_ value of `$path`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, ah, so `$path = try {` isn't valid. Saw that in a different example somewhere. VERY happy my mistake wasn't in moving to OOP. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, it's perfectly valid code, but it is indeed what causes the undesirable behavior your seeing :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So, is there a situation where that idiom is a good answer, i.e. no misbehavior? Or is this one of those cases where it's valid code, that never works?

Comment: It's not "misbehavior" - it's simply you asking powershell to do _something_ and expecting it to do something else. As I mentioned above - the entire `try`/`catch` block needs to execute before its value can be (re-)assigned to `$path` - so referencing `$path` _inside_ the `try`/`catch` block will resolve the value of `$path` from before.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in the question. But it sounds like that particular idiom can never be expected to work in a useful way. But it won't get flagged as an error, because it is "valid" code. kind of like `If 1 -eq 2` is valid code, but not particularly useful. In any case, it's fixed and working now, and I can get on with the registry stuff. Woot, since Netherlands closed all the bars so nothing else top do on a Sunday night. :)

Comment: Sure it can. `$path = try {[PxPath]::new($testitem)}catch{@{Type="Error";Description="Error"}}; Write-Host $path.Description` <-- here we wait to reference any properties of `$path` until _after_ the assignment has completed - useful :)

Comment: Aha! Now I am following. I think I have some experiments to do, to decide how to proceed. Actually a rather useful "failure" I had there, since I learned something useful in the process.